# Learning roadmap for Non-commutative Geometry

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

I am interested in learning Non-commutative geometry and K-theory of operator algebras. Please suggest a learning roadmap for this subject. My present knowledge of Measure theory & Functional Analysis is very little.Please advise which topics in Functional Analysis and Operator Theory should I learn before starting Alain Connes' book 'Non Commutative Geometry' and references for the same. What are other prerequisites for reading this book ?

Comment: Before learning all the operator algebras perhaps learn some basic functional analysis? This [link](http://tqft.net/web/teaching/2013/Analysis3/) may be useful.

Comment: Ask your advisor. And you should probably learn basic graduate real analysis first...

Comment: That's way too many tags, and one of them should be self-learning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend that you learn some Operator Algbras first, from say Murphy's *Operator Algebras and Operator Theory*. Then you can learn some K-theory from Rordam/Larsen/Laustsen's book *Introduction to K-theory for Operator Algebras*.

After that, you should be knowledgeable enough to find your own way around.